# Subtracting one arrayList from another arrayList

Tags: java

I have two arrayLists and I am trying to "subtract" one arrayList from another. For example, if I have one arrayList [1,2,3] and I am trying to subtract [0, 2, 4] the resulting arrayList should be [1,3].

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4);
subtract(a,b) // should return [1,3]
```

Here is my code.

```
//returns a new IntSet after subtracting a from b
// .minus().toString()
ArrayList<Integer> minusArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    minusArray.addAll(array1);

    for(int i =0; i< minusArray.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++){
            if(minusArray.get(i).equals(array2.get(j))){
                minusArray.remove(i);
                if(i == 0){
                    ;
                }
                else if(j == 0){
                    ;
                }
                else{
                    i = 0;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
            else{}
        }
    }

return minusArray;
```

My code works in some cases, like if `arrayList1 = [4,6]` and `arrayList2 = [6]` it will will give me a result of `[4]`. But if I try something like `[1,2,4]` and `[0,4,8]`

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at IntSet.minus(IntSet.java:119)
    at IntSetDriver.main(IntSetDriver.java:62)
```

Here is the code I have come up with. I have done test runs through it and to me I think it should work. The user inputs these arrayLists and they are presorted, I also do not know Hash or big-O.

```
ArrayList<Integer> minusArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    minusArray.addAll(array1);

    for(int i =0; i< minusArray.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++){
            if(minusArray.get(i).equals(array2.get(j))){
                minusArray.remove(i);
            }
            else{}
        }
    }

return minusArray;
```

Comment: Since your code tests `equals()` on each element in the array and removes `if true`. You can simply use `removeAll()` like suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23172547/1485527. Or am I missing something? If you want only remove the first occurrence go with Apache Utils or plain java, like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415419/1485527. Otherwise I'd like to suggest to provide your solution in form of an answer, and explain why it is the best.  Including the answer into the question breaks Q&A style.

Comment: Java 8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850546/1216775

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that in your minusArray.remove(...) call you may shrink the size of the minusArray. To fix this, start at array.size() - 1 and count backwards to 0

Check that - even that won't fix it. You need to reverse the order of your loops

Answer (score 64):

Is there some reason you can't simply use List.removeAll(List)?

```
    List<Integer> one = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    one.add(1);
    one.add(2);
    one.add(3);
    List<Integer> two = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    two.add(0);
    two.add(2);
    two.add(4);
    one.removeAll(two);
    System.out.println(one);

    result: "[1, 3]"
```

Comment: `removeAll(2)` will remove all occurrences of `2` which is not how subtracting is defined usually. Usually it is meant to remove only on occurrence of `2`.  Correct? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415419/1485527

Comment: Unspecified by the OP. But, the code posted seems to be attempting to remove all in the inner for{} loop. Looks like that's the intention?

Comment: hm, your right. It tests for `remove()` on all elements. So this should clearly be the accepted answer. I will still leave my answer at this place for further reference.

Comment: > this should clearly be the accepted answer

Feel free to tell the OP that. ;)

Answer (score 45):

Try to use subtract method of org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils class.

Returns a new Collection containing a - b. The cardinality of each element e in the returned Collection will be the cardinality of e in a minus the cardinality of e in b, or zero, whichever is greater.

```
CollectionUtils.subtract(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)
```

From [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html)

Comment: @kukis CS 251 will be a second year computer science course at some university.

Comment: In java 8 you can do `b.forEach((i)->a.remove(i));` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415419/1485527 for further info.

Answer (score 23):

### Java 8

You can also use streams:

```
List<Integer> list1 =  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list2 =  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5);
List<Integer> diff = list1.stream()
                          .filter(e -> !list2.contains(e))
                          .collect (Collectors.toList()); // (3)
```

This answer does not manipulate the original list. If intention is to modify the original list then we can use `remove`. Also we can use `forEach` (default method in `Iterator`) or stream with filter.

### Using ListUtils

Another option is to use `ListUtils` if we are using Apache common:

```
ListUtils.subtract(list, list2)
```

This subtracts all elements in the second list from the first list, placing the results in a new list. This differs from `List.removeAll(Collection)` in that **cardinality is respected**; if list1 contains two occurrences of `null` and list2 only contains one occurrence, then the returned list will still contain one occurrence.

Comment: How is this better than `list1.removeAll(list2)` ? In my opinion ( [and others](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ApacheCommonCollectionsEquivalents)) this is not subtracting, because it removes all occurrences of a value in list2 from list1. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jschnasse it returns the difference between two lists and yes it is subtraction. Here intention is to return result rather than manipulating the original list. If we want to remove from original list then we can use remove.

Comment: I feel ...though it works , ....its not a good at all !
thats because:
    1) when no of elements is less in each list, u must not use stream
    2) .contains( ) is not always the criteria for equality(not OP case)
         eg. what if 
                 remove all strings from list1<String> when any element of list1 
                 is substring of list2<String>
     3) sometimes Stream1.operation is dependent on Stream2.criteria, then 
         too many string colludes the memory and degrades latency

Happy if sum1 tells I'm wrong and suggests best optimized + efficient solutions

Answer (score 7):

Traversing the `minusArray` using an index is one way to do this, but I suggest you make use of the `contains(Object)` method, which will allow you then to use `remove(Object)` for the particular element of `array2`.

Of course, there's always the `removeAll(Collection)` which does pretty much everything you need...

Answer (score 6):

You can use org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils and make all that you want in only one line =)

```
List resultList = ListUtils.subtract(list, list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you get the range problem because you've eliminated one of the elements which changes what the inner loop is looking for (I know this problem occurs when dealing with normal Lists and Collections).

What I've had to do in the past to work around this, is to create a list of items that need to be removed (that is ones that are found in the original list).  Iterate through that new list and directly eliminate the original list's elements without having to have an iterator moving through it.

Answer (score 2):

> Try this answer **if `removeAll()`** **is not what you want**. e.g. if you are interested in something like [Calculating difference of two lists with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410929)

**subtract(a,b)**

```
b.forEach((i)->a.remove(i));
```

`a` now contains

```
[1, 3]
```

This follows the [suggestion of Guava implementors](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ApacheCommonCollectionsEquivalents) on how to implement subtract

> "create an ArrayList containing a and then call remove on it for each element in b."

Which behaves like [this implementation used in Apache commons](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections/blob/collections-4.1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.java#L330)

**Difference to removeAll()**

```
[1,2,2,3].removeAll([1,2,3]) //is empty
[1,2,3].forEach((i)->[1,2,2,3].remove(i)); //a is [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

My parameterized solution would be like:

```
<T> ArrayList<T> subtract(ArrayList<T> alpha, ArrayList<T> beta) {
    ArrayList<T> gamma = new ArrayList<T>();
    alpha.forEach(n -> {if (!beta.contains(n)) gamma.add(n); });
    return gamma;
}
```