# Remove all objects from list that does not exist in another list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, java-collections-api

I have two list

```
    List<Map<String,Object>> list1 =  new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    List<Map<String,Object>> list2 =  new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put("1", new Long(1L));
    HashMap<String, Object> hm2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm2.put("2", new Long(2L));
    HashMap<String, Object> hm3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm3.put("3", new Long(3L));
    HashMap<String, Object> hm4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm4.put("4", new Long(4L));

    list1.add(hm);
    list1.add(hm2);
    list1.add(hm3);
    list1.add(hm4);

    HashMap<String, Object> hm1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm1.put("1", new Long(1L));
    HashMap<String, Object> hm5 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm5.put("2", new Long(2L));

    list2.add(hm1);
    list2.add(hm5);
```

I want to remove all objects from list1 that does not exist in another list2 
My expected output is `list1 -- [{2=2, 1=1}]`

I can Iterate through list1 and can check if element present then do nothing else remove the element. But I want to know is there a better approach or simpler code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888265/remove-all-objects-in-an-arraylist-that-exist-in-another-arraylist?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_43"

Comment: Do you mean to aggregate the contents of the HashMaps as well?, or did you intend the expected output to be `[{"2"=2L},{"1"=1L}]` ?

Comment: I intend to have the output `[{"2"=2L},{"1"=1L}]`

Comment: @austinwernli is not a duplicated, because the other question ask 
exactly the reverse case...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`Collection.retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) method exists for exactly that purpose:

> Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection. In other words, removes from this collection all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

Usage would be:

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
```

It might not be any more efficient than a naive iteration approach, however, unless you use `Set`s instead of `List`s.