# Calculating difference of two lists with duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, java-stream

I have two lists.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4));
```

I want to remove the elements contained in `list2` from `list1`, precisely as many times as they are contained in `list2`. In the example above: when we remove elements in list 1 which exist in list 2, we should get as result `[1, 2]` (only one occurrence of `2` should be removed from `list1` because `list2` contains only one instance of `2`).

I tried with `list1.removeAll(list2);` but I got as result list containing only `[1]`.

What is the best way to achieve this? Iterate through both lists simultaneous seems a bit ugly for me.

Comment: "1 and 2 and not only 1" - I don't get it, could you post the resulting list?

Comment: ...So you're looking for the intersection of these lists?

Comment: Please rewrite the part *"I want to have the resulting list that only contains the removed elements once"* to make it better understandable for us :-)

Comment: the way people are downvoted answers here is not fair. you just close this question because it's not well formulated .. It need to be explained more clearer.

Comment: @arthur:  It makes sense to downvote answers which don't fully understand the question.  An answer which is not germane to the question is, by definition, *wrong*.

Comment: @arthur What exactly is not fair in downvoting answer which is incorrect? For instance starman1979 provided answer which does exactly same as `list1.removeAll(list2);` so what OP uses currently. higz555 provided answer which basically removes duplicates from each lists, but this also doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Pshemo you don't understand. The question ist not well formulated, and people are writting a solution to something that is not clear. What does he want "1 and 2 and not only 1" ??   "1 and 2" could mean anything from the distinct in each List, to the removal in all Lists. Man should just be clear

Comment: @arthur I am not sure how your comment is related to what I said. It was response to what you said earlier "the way people are downvoted answers here is not fair" which if I am not mistaken is complain that people are downvoting answers to unclear question. But some of us didn't downvote because of that, but because answers ware simply wrong (question may be not clear in 100%, but often 80% which is clear is enough to tell if answer can be correct or not, like I shown in my previous comment).

Comment: @Pshemo ok, I  see

Comment: @Pshemo See what is the accepted answer now. Maybe downvoters were wrong?! SO should be more about upvotes. Instantly downvoting feels destructive to me. It kind of interrupts the communication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to remove a single `2` element from `list1` rather than all of them.  You can iterate over `list2` and attempt to remove each element from `list1`. Keep in mind that there are more efficient methods than this if `list2` cannot contain duplicates.

```
var list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 2));
var list2 = List.of(2, 3, 4);

list2.forEach(list1::remove);
```

`list1` now contains the following:

```
[1, 2]
```

See [starman1979's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411110/7294647) for the same solution, but using a lambda rather than a method reference.

Comment: could you explain why this is better than what was suggested by @starman1979 ?

Comment: +1 for showing us `var`. https://medium.com/@afinlay/java-10-sneak-peek-local-variable-type-inference-var-3022016e1a2b

Comment: @jschnasse I didn't even see their answer before posting mine, but theirs looks correct.  I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Sorry but how is that different than `list1.removeAll(list2);` which OP is already using?

Comment: @Pshemo `List#removeAll` removes all elements (not just one) from `list1` that are contained in `list2`.

Comment: @jschnasse the other answer is an (almost) code-only answer and very likely has been put into the low-quality review queue automatically and there, it apparently faced draconic reviewers, not actually looking for the correctness of the code.

Comment: @Pshemo `list.removeAll(other)` is like `list.removeIf(other::contains)` whereas this solution is `other.forEach(list::remove)`. The difference between them is exactly what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
list2.forEach(i -> {
    list1.remove(i); //removes only first occurrence - if found
});
```

`list1` now contains

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and what OP has?

Comment: +1 for first attempt and providing at least the desired result. @Pshemo if downvoting, maybe come up with a more elegant solution?

Comment: @jschnasse OK I was wrong. Didn't pay attention to fact that `remove` deletes only *first* occurrence of specified element, not *all* of them. But that is also why I posted my first comment here. Answer shouldn't only contain solution, explanation of problem and description how/why solution solves it is also important.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change my vote unless answer will be edited (and I will not upvote it unless it will contain some explanation of why/how it solves the problem).

Comment: Sorry guys, should have elaborated more.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2));
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4);
```

Use one of the following variants to get the desired result:

**1. Plain java**

```
b.forEach((i)->a.remove(i));
```

`a` now contains

```
[1, 2]
```

Give credit at original post: [add **+1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411110/1485527):

**2. Apache Commons**

In [apache commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1) there is a `subtract` method

```
Collection<Integer> result = CollectionUtils.subtract(a, b);
```

`result` now contains

```
[1, 2]
```

Here is [how they implemented it](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.java#L302)

**3. Guava**

Since guava doesn't offer a `subtract` method you may find [this advice from the google implementors](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ApacheCommonCollectionsEquivalents) helpful

> "create an ArrayList containing a and then call remove on it for each element in b."

Which basically renders to what was already mentioned under **1.**