# Reactor filter out Flux<String> from List<String>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Suppose we have

- `List<String> list` contains `"A", "B", "C", "D"`
- `Flux<String> flux` contains `"A", "B"`

Is there a way to filter out flux from list? In other words, subtract flux from list, where the results should be `"C", "D"`.

Looking through the documentation for reactor, `filterWhen` seems to be the closest, but it only replays the first element match the condition, all subsequent matches will be ignored.

This can be easily achieved in non-reactive world, for List or Collections, e.g. [Subtracting one arrayList from another arrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933403/subtracting-one-arraylist-from-another-arraylist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that you are looking to use the [`collectList()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) method.

`Flux::collectList` will take a `Flux<String>` and emit a `Mono<List<String>>`.

This will conveniently give you the ability to run whatever collection comparison operation you need to run over that dataset.

With that you can provide a `.map()` operation that operates and converts it to your desired results.

```
Mono<List<String>> monoWithRemovedElements = flux.collectList()
    .map(fluxTurnedIntoList -> /*(subtract array list)*/)
```

If you would like to fan this back out into a Flux you can use the `Mono::flatMapMany` method.

```
Flux<String> fluxWithRemovedElements = monoWithRemovedElements 
   .flatMapMany(list -> Flux.fromIterable(list))
```

Comment: Thank you, clever trick to convert `Flux` to a `List`

Answer (score 0):

you need to first convert the Flux into ArrayList and then remove the elements from the list based on what elements are in Flux.

```
List<String> fluxedList = flux.collectList().block();
fluxedList.stream().forEach( elem -> list.remove(elem));
```